# Git - Selective Branching

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a Git repository at github with files, `file_1` and `file_2` in the master branch. I need to have another branch 'selective' with only `file_2` in it. What I did was that, I created a new branch with the checkout command. Then I deleted `file_1` and committed. Now master branch has 2 files, `file_1` and `file_2` and selective branch only has `file_2`. I can specifically make changes and commit `file_2` for both branches. I got what I wanted. Unless I merge selective with master, there is no problem whatsoever. Is this the way to do it? Or Is there any other better way available?

My aim is that I want my client to access only certain files in my codebase, i.e. my master branch. I need only want those files which I want the client to access in the other branch.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the right way to do this is to have a clean repository without any history for data share with the customer and use it as a submodule (plus use a script in your main project to set up your whole tree). This way you're leaking older version of the file that you don't want to share.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would add to that setup a:

```
git checkout selective
git merge -s ours master
```

That will record a merge between `selective` and `master` (while retaining `selective` changes, here specifically the deletion of `file1`)

That will ensure that the next merge from `master` to `selective` will update only `file2`, and would not restore `file1` in selective branch.

Comment: that was an excellent tweak. Thanks!. So can I conclude that this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$ git checkout -b selective_branch
$ git branch
master
* selective_branch

$ git checkout master -- file_2
$ git commit -m "Update file_2 from master"

$ # make changes in file2 in master branch
$ git checkout master
$ git branch
* master
selective_branch
$ git status -s
M file_2
$ git add file_2

$ git commit -m 'Added abc function in file_2'
$ git push origin master


$ # make changes in file2 in selective branch
$ git checkout selective_branch
$ git branch
master
* selective_branch
$ git status -s
M file_2
$ git add file_2

$ git commit -m 'Added abc function in file_2'
$ git push origin selective_branch


$ # Now merge the changes from selective_branch to master branch. Switch the branch to master
$ git checkout master
$ git branch
* master
selective_branch
$ git merge origin/selective_branch
$ # After Merge Master and selective_branch will point to same Commit ID
$ # After testing you can push the changes to the master branch
$ git push origin master
```